# Automate Post Of Login Details User & Password Into Safari For Scraping

Tags: post, variables, applescript, web-scraping

I am wanting to automate the input of post variables on a login page for the purpose of webscraping.  It would improve the process no end if I can get past the login page.

Then I can schedule some functions to run on cycle automatically.  (Had a go with some CURL commands but could not get the result)

Thanks for any help,

lance

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [this article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080205190647941) for some suggestions.

The magic part is:

```
tell application "Safari"
  activate
  tell (make new document) to set URL to "https://www.fedex.com/ship/shipEntryAction.do?method=doInitialEntry&origincountry=us&locallang=en&urlparams=us&sType=&programIndicator=0"
  delay 2

  set doc to document "FedEx | Ship Manager | Shipping"
  log (doc's name)
  do JavaScript "document.forms['domesticShipmentActionForm']['recipient.companyName'].value = 'add'" in doc
  do JavaScript "submitForm('doSelectRecipientCompanyName')" in doc
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) to do this. You can fully automate your tests, or you could just leave the browser open at the end and continue on your own manually.

For example, a login might look like:

```
GotoURL http://somesite.com/
SubmitForm with
  %Params% with
    %name% mylogin
    %pass% mypassword
  end
end
```

It works with both a browserless mode or with a backing browser. I've only tested that with explorer and firefox, but I'd be happy to help you get it running with Safari if you want.